# What does "#$" mean in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, syntax

Say for example a script begins like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -l hostname=qn*
```

and then later down the page the actual script comes into play. My question is what does the "#$" symbol mean or do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you by any means running on a **batch cluster**? Like Sun Grid Engine? There might be special meanings in scripts intended to run as a batch job.

https://www.wiki.ed.ac.uk/display/EaStCHEMresearchwik/How+to+write+a+SGE+job+submission+script

**Update:**

above link blocks when used from stackoverflow.com (works from google.com)

alternatives:

- http://www.cbi.utsa.edu/sge_tutorial
- http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/HPC/basement/sge/SGE.html

Comment: next time, instead of editing and removing most of your answer just write another one, the previous content of your answer may be useful to others.

Comment: well, i had just pointed out, that i had seen `#$`been used for options. But than i remembered having seen that, while i was using batch jobs, so i specified the answer.

Comment: Yes, the script is used to run a command on a cluster. By the way, that link requires a login with a university account so I can't access it.

Comment: Funny link, if you copy paste the link into google search, the exact same link will be the first hit. And then it will work. Seems they have some kind of referer check in place.

Answer (score 6):

Lines beginning with `#` are comments. The first line may begin with `#!`, but it's still a comment to `bash` and is merely used to indicate the interpreter to use for the file. All other lines beginning with `#` are absolutely unimportant to `bash`, whether the next character is `$` or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

They seem to be parameters for the Oracle (ex-Sun) Grid Engine, look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587053/timeout-jobs-on-sun-grid-engine) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320976/sungridengine-condor-torque-as-resource-managers-for-pvm).

They are heavily using these kind of comments.

Answer (score 0):

Those line are important for queue systems like sbatch.